# Upgrading from bootstrap 3 to 5 causes all sizing to be enlarged

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

When I upgraded from bootstrap 3 to 5, it resulted in an enlargement issue of all the elements in every page of my app. All the components in this image do not use bootstrap with the exception of the dropdown menu (three vertical dots).

[image: Before upgrading]
[image: After upgrading]

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What's viewport looking like for HTML output?

Comment: Between 3 and version 5 have a deep difference, like breakpoints, class, dependency, etc I think you can migrate from 3 to 5 in terms of structure.

Comment: Hi, do you mean this?

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change all the CSS and elements to match your new framework.  There's no "easy fix" when upgrading, you just go through each element that doesn't look right and change it.

Answer (score 0):

The default font size has been changed. If the size of the web elements is proportional to the font, you should change the font size.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#global-changes